# Using vim to remotely edit a file on serverB only accessible from serverA

Tags: vim, ssh, remote-access, scp

Although I have never tried this, it is apparently possible to remotely edit a file in vim as described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim). In my particular case the server I need access to can only be accessed from on campus, hence I have to log into my university account like so:

```
ssh user@login.university.com
```

then from there log into the secure server like so:

```
ssh user@secure.university.com
```

I have keyless ssh set up, so I can automate the process like so:

```
ssh user@login.university.com -t "ssh user@secure.university.com"
```

is there anyway to remotely edit a file such as `secure.university.com/user/foo.txt` on my local machine?

**EDIT:**

My intention is to use vim on my local machine as it is impractical (move `.vim folder`, copy `.vimrc`) and in some cases impossible (recompile vim with certain settings, patch vim source, install language beautifiers) to make vim on the remote machine behave the way I want it to behave. What I want is to issue something like this (this is not accurate scp, I know)

```
vim scp://user@login.university.com scp://user@secure.university.com//home/user/foo.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK after a little working around I figured it out. First you have to edit (or create) your `.ssh/config` file as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/174160/scp-over-a-proxy-with-one-command-from-local-machine). For our purposes, we will add a line like this, which essentially adds a proxy.

```
Host secure
  User          Julius
  HostName      secure.university.com
  ProxyCommand  ssh Tiberius@login.university.com nc %h %p 2> /dev/null
```

Then we can simply copy (via `scp`) the file `secure.university.com:/home/Julius/fee/fie/fo/fum.txt` to the local computer like so

```
scp secure:/home/Julius/fee/fie/fo/fum.txt fum.txt
```

Extending on this, we can load it into vim remotely like so:

```
vim scp://secure//home/Julius/fee/fie/fo/fum.txt
```

or using `badd` like so:

```
:badd scp://secure//home/Julius/fee/fie/fo/fum.txt
```

To simplify my life, I added this shortcut to my `.vimrc` file for the most commonly used subfolder:

```
nnoremap <leader>scp :badd scp://secure//home/Julius/fee/fie/fo/fum.txt
```

So far vim has proven to be pretty aware that this is a remote file, so if the C file includes a file like so:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

it won't complain that "foo.h" is missing

Answer (score 0):

Once you SSHed in the machine you can run any command(also vim) in remote host on your shell. After logging run vim as you are running in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ssh, you basically have access to the server via the CLI, as if you were sitting in front of the machine itself.  With that said, you can use any program on that machine, just like you would use it on your own machine.  Assuming that the `secure.university.com/user/foo.txt` means that there is a text file called `foo.txt` at location `/user` on the secure server, then the following commands would work after logging in through ssh:

```
cd /user
vim foo.txt
```

You could also use nano or any other CLI based editor that is installed on the machine.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must not have made it clear enough that I would like to remotely edit in vim. I will update my question to reflect this